# D3 -- Nested piechart not displaying all wedges

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've been having a bunch of trouble with a pie chart I've been trying to make. I finally have the outer ring working, but the inner ring only displays a few of the pieces (out ring has 3, inner ring has 6 but displays 3).

Does anyone know what might be wrong with this code? Both systems work fine on their own, but for whatever reason they don't work when I put them together.

The wedges for 20, 10 and 5 are the ones that don't display, and it happens that way every single time.

The name of the class ("arc") doesn't seem to matter, either.

```
function makeDonut(svg) {
  var boundingBox = d3.select(svg).node().getBoundingClientRect();
  var h = boundingBox.height;
  var w = boundingBox.width;

  /*****   donut chart  *****/

  var data = [25, 40, 55];
  // arbitrary data

  var outerRadius = w/3;
  var innerRadius = 3*(outerRadius/4);
  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

  var pie = d3.pie();

  // order: gold, silver, bronze
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(['#e5ce0c', '#e5e4e0', '#a4610a']);

  var arcs = d3.select(svg).selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + ((h-25)/2) + ")");

  arcs.append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity', .7);

  })
  .on('mouseleave', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity', 1);
  });

  arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });

    /************ piechart ************/

    var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ];
    // arbitrary dataset

    var outerRadius2 = 0.75 * (w/3);
    var innerRadius2 = 0;

    var arc2 = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius2)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius2);

    var pie2 = d3.pie();

    var color2 = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);


    var arcs2 = d3.select(svg).selectAll("g.arc")
      .data(pie2(dataset))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + ((h-25)/2) + ")");

    //Draw arc paths
    arcs2.append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color2(i);
      })
      .attr("d", arc2);

    arcs2.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The D3 enter method creates elements in the DOM where needed so that for every item in the data array there is an appropriate element in the DOM.

For your donut chart, which you draw first, you `selectAll("g.arc")` - there are no `g` elements with the class `arc`, you have an empty selection. So when you use the enter method, D3 creates one element for every item in the data array. Everything chained to `.enter()`, without a `.merge()` method, only affects these entered elements.

For your pie chart, which you draw second, you `selectAll("g.arc")` - however, now there are three `g` elements with the class `arc`. So when you use the enter method here, the enter selection does not included elements for the first three items in the data array: *they already exist*. Instead these first three elements are included in the update selection.

This functionality is core to the D3 enter/update/exit cycle.

If you want to enter everything, and aren't updating or exiting data points, then you can simply use `.selectAll(null)` which will create an empty selection, for which an enter selection will create an element for every item in the data array.

If you wanted to modify these wedges/arcs later, you could differentiate the two, either by entering them in different `g` elements (eg: `g1.selectAll("g.arc")` and `g2.selectAll("g.arc")`. Alternatively, you could give them different class names based on whether pie or donut, as below:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
  var boundingBox = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect();
  var h = boundingBox.height;
  var w = boundingBox.width;

  /*****   donut chart  *****/

  var data = [25, 40, 55];
  // arbitrary data

  var outerRadius = w/3;
  var innerRadius = 3*(outerRadius/4);
  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

  var pie = d3.pie();

  // order: gold, silver, bronze
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(['#e5ce0c', '#e5e4e0', '#a4610a']);

  var arcs = svg.selectAll("donut")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "donut")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + ((h-25)/2) + ")");

  arcs.append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity', .7);

  })
  .on('mouseleave', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity', 1);
  });

  arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });

    /************ piechart ************/

    var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ];
    // arbitrary dataset

    var outerRadius2 = 0.75 * (w/3);
    var innerRadius2 = 0;

    var arc2 = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius2)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius2);

    var pie2 = d3.pie();

    var color2 = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);


    var arcs2 = svg.selectAll(".pie")
      .data(pie2(dataset))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "pie")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + ((h-25)/2) + ")");

    //Draw arc paths
    arcs2.append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color2(i);
      })
      .attr("d", arc2);

    arcs2.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width=500 height=400></svg>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I didn't realize DOM elements worked that way, it makes a lot more sense now. I changed the class names.